# Display Multiple Raster Grids as Triangles Instead of Squares

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay, display

I am looking to show a negative correlation between two raster datasets (distance to nearest agricultural market and nighttime luminosity) and think it'd be fun to be able to show viewers the raw data from both layers rather than having a single layer showing some calculated statistic. To accomplish this, my goal is to have one of the two rasters shown as a grid of triangles instead of squares, occupying only half the space they currently do so that when both layers are turned on in QGIS I can see both together at once. I am having a lot of trouble altering the display of the raster away from squares because this is of course central to the definition of what a raster is.

The two layers I'm working with for reference;
[NightLights](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Eg1HlYwYIhKUSq_dtUvDQb0bMOvMhJs/view?usp=share_link) & [Distance to Market](https://drive.google.com/file/d/107Nj4H49TrrjT92UjBXfANAH4aALAQdm/view?usp=share_link).

I have tried transforming the raster grids to polygons, which I could then transform to triangles via the method described in [Coloring only half raster polygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219228), but then lose the ability to display the continuous underlying data along a color ramp which is so easily done on raster layers.

Is it possible to alter the display of a raster from an array of squares to an array of triangles?

I am using QGIS for this work.